# Migration Question

Tags: migration

I am trying to figure out if I understand the migration process correctly for a very important migration I have planned.

1. I am currently hosting a clients site as an `Add On` domain on my personal account.
   **www.example.com**
2. I have created an account for them on my reseller WHM system using the same domain name.
   **www.example.com**
3. I have copied all of their files from the personal hosting account I have to my HD.
4. I am leaving their MySQL DB and MySQL DB User accounts alone in case anything goes wrong.
5. I have created a backup of their DB.

Now as far as I understand it, all I have to do is the following:

1. Remove the `Add On` domain from my personal account.
   This will delete their folders on my server myaccount/public_html/example.com
2. Change the Nameserver to point to the new reseller account I created for them.
3. Transfer the copied files and folders to their account on the reseller system.
4. Import the DB to the new server.
5. Minor adjustments.
   Like the new DB name won't be mypersonalhostingaccount_dbname it will be newaccount_dbname and the password will need adjusting, etc.

But this SHOULD make the site officially transfer without losing anything... and if something get's screwed up, theoretically I could just delete their new hosting account, re-initiate the `Add On` domain on my account, re-upload the files, and the site would be right back where it started?

I'm just really concerned about losing anything... anyone care to chime in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) about migration in codex. That's a good start. When migrating there are no special tricks, you just have to upload your files to new location and change some datas in your DB to tell WordPress your website has a new location.

Be cautious with those 3 wp options tables which have to be updated :

1. home
2. siteurl
3. fileupload_url

Answer (score 0):

[BackupBuddy](http://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/) is your friend, it ain't cheap but when you meet the requirements it's a live saver for sure.

Comment: would you have any idea why my admin panel is gone or missing?

Comment: did you use Backup Buddy? I have not encountered problems with migrations with them. You do have frontend but no dashboard?

Comment: Yeah. wp-admin is dead. The files are there. But I get the 500 server error...

Comment: could be permissions on index.php, but I'm guessing it's a plugin or theme function. Try removing plugins and themes, make sure the WP has like twentytwelve to use as fallback. Than try to locate problem by activating theme again of activate plugins one by one.

Comment: you used importbuddy script? The zip it created forehand on the "old" domain is successfully created?

Comment: Yes. Yeah, if you re-read the question you'll see I wasn't changing domain names... I was moving from an `Add On` domain on my personal hosting account to a business account on a reseller with it's own cpanel. I used BackUp Buddy to create the backup and ImportBuddy.php to restore the backup.

It's a multi-site with only one site.

Comment: yeah I understand, iv'e / we've done the same. Im digging deep, not a computer at my disposal atm, so head work. Last we had an issue that the home URL and site URL would not update in the DB. And we did the update site URL thing in the wp-config. Think iv'e read than that MP's needs to be manually updated in the DB.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_URL_directly_in_the_database

Comment: Alright... I stumbled across a post somewhere that said it could be plugins. So I started renaming the plugin folders and it works. Now I gotta figure out how to a) figure out which plugin it is exactly b) reinstall the offending pluging c) not lose any data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9217/discussion-between-randomblink-and-kortschot)